# How to create obj file using cl.exe

Tags: c, cl

I have a header (.h) and a c (.c) file. How can I create an object .obj file using them in cl.exe ?

Comment: I think you're looking for this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s7c9wdw.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cl /Wall /Fo foo.obj foo.c
```

Explanation:

`/Wall` enables more warnings. You want this!

`/Fo foo.obj`   creates an object file named foo.obj

`foo.c`  This is your input C file. It must `#include "yourHeaderFile.h"`

Comment: Try adding `/c` as the first parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If necessary, you may include .h file in your .c file.

```
#include "xxxxx.h"
```

Use /c to compile only without linking.

To sum up,

```
cl /c xxxxx.c
```